# observables, arrays and filtering

Tags: arrays, angular, rxjs, observable, angular-filters

using angular 8, rxjs 6.5.2

I have an http call which returns an observable of

```
{
  'A': {name: 'A', type:'1'},
  'B': {name: 'B', type:'2'},
  'C': {name: 'C', type:'2'}
}
```

I store this call in `data$`

I want to show all type "2" in the angular form. I know that to convert an object into an array, I can use `Object.values(data)`

so how do I convert the observable into an array which can then be filtered and changed back into an observable ?

I have tried this code

```
    this.myService.getPeople().subscribe(data => {
        const items = Object.values(data).filter(
            (item: any) => item && item.type === '2'
        );

        this.data$ = of(items);
    });
```

but the form never updates or refreshes

Am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: Your first example is not a valid JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use map operator.

```
this.data$ = this.myService.getPeople().pipe(map(data => {
            const items = Object.values(data).filter(
                (item: any) => item && item.type === '2'
            );
              return items;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your component uses the ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush.

In that case, you need to add a ChangeDetectorRef to your component's constructor parameters:

```
constructor(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, ...) {
...
}
```

then change your data fetching function to this:

```
this.myService.getPeople().subscribe(data => {
            const items = Object.values(data).filter(
                (item: any) => item && item.type === '2'
            );
            this.data$ = of(items);
            this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
        });
```